# Unix shell-scripting: Can find-result be made independent of string capitalization?

Tags: shell

First I'm not a star with shell-scripting, more used to programming in Python, but have to work with an existing Python script which calls Unix commands via subprocess.

In this script we use 2 find commands to check if 2 certain strings can be found in an xml file / file-name:

```
FIND_IN_FILE_CMD: find <directory> -name *.xml -exec grep -Hnl STRING1|STRING2 {} +
FIND_IN_FILENAME_CMD: find <directory> ( -name *STRING1*xml -o -name *STRING2*xml )
```

The problem we saw is that STRING1 and STRING2 are not always written capitalized.
Now I can do something like `STRING1|STRING2|String1|String2|string1|string2` and  `( -name *STRING1*xml -o -name *STRING2*xml -o -name *String1*xml -o -name *String2*xml -o -name *string1*xml -o -name *string2*xml )`, but I was wondering if there was something more efficient to do this check in one go which basically matches all different writing styles.

Can anybody help me with that?

Comment: `-name` is a case sensitive match.  `-iname` is case insensitive.

Comment: What operating system are you using? The options available to tools like `grep` and `find` change on different OSs. Note that both `find` commands you show will give syntax errors. Have you tried them? Did they work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your commands have syntax errors:

```
$ find -name *.xml -exec grep -Hnl STRING1|STRING2 {} +
bash: STRING2: command not found
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

This is because you cannot have an unquoted `|` in a shell command as that is taken as a pipe symbol. As you can see above, the shell tries to execute `STRING2` as a command. In any case, `grep` cannot understand `|` unless you use the `-E` flag or, if your `grep` supports it, the `-P` flag. For vanilla `grep`, you need `STRING1\|STRING2`.

All implementations of `grep` should support the [POSIX-mandated](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) `-i` and `-E` options:

```
-E
Match using extended regular expressions. Treat each pattern specified as an ERE, as described in XBD Extended Regular Expressions. If any entire ERE pattern matches some part of an input line excluding the terminating <newline>, the line shall be matched. A null ERE shall match every line.
-i
Perform pattern matching in searches without regard to case; see XBD Regular Expression General Requirements.
```

This means you can use `-i` for case insensitive matching and `-E` for extended regular expressions, making your command:

```
find <directory> -name '*.xml' -exec grep -iEHnl 'STRING1|STRING2' {} +
```

Note how I also quoted the `*.xml` since without the quotes, if any `xml` files
are present in the directory you ran the command in, then `*.xml` would be expanded by the shell to the list of `xml` files in *that* directory.

Your next command also has issues:

```
$ find ( -name *STRING1*xml -o -name *STRING2*xml )
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `-name'
```

This is because the `(` has a special meaning in the shell (it opens a subshell) so you need to escape it (`\(`). As for case insensitive matching, GNU `find`, the default on Linux has an `-iname` option which is equivalent to `-name` but case insensitive. If you are using GNU `find`, then you can do:

```
find <directory> \( -iname '*STRING1*xml' -o -iname '*STRING2*xml' \)
```

If your `find` doesn't have `-iname`, you are stuck with writing out all possible permutations. In all cases, however, you will need to quote the patterns and escape the parentheses as I have done above.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.
I translated working Python subprocess commands-lists into the commandline command I thought they would translate into. But probably did that wrong ;-)
For example In the subprocess command list I saw "STRING1\|STRING2" but I thought that the "\|" was a Python escape for "|". And since subprocess concatenates the different parts of the command list I thought that I could remove the quotes around this "STRING1\|STRING2".
Like I said I'm not a shell expert, more a shell newby who can understand what others write, but not make it good myself 8-)

Comment: @Nemelis yeah, subprocess also automatically quotes the arguments, if I'm not mistaken. And yes, this kind of thing is deceptively complicated despite appearing simple. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to continue using `find`, just replace `-name` with the case insensitive version `-iname`.

Comment: Note that `-iname` is not POSIX and might not be supported by all `find` implementations. I know GNU `find`, BSD `find` and even busybox `find` have it, but since it isn't POSIX, I'm sure others won't.

Comment: -iname is support by the OS of my customer (Redhat Linux 7).

@William Pursell: Even though you were the first to mention -iname. I give the solution checkmark to terdon due to his explanation gave me a lot of extra insight. But still kudos to you